# Vmware not accepting clipboard form parent OS

Tags: vmware, vmware-player

I am using VMware 12 on my Windows 8 OS. I run Ubuntu 14.04 on VMware. I use both windows and Ubuntu together. The text copied into clipboard in windows cannot be pasted in Ubuntu and vice-versa. I tried using both Ctrl-C- Ctrl-V and also with mouse copying and pasting. This was working in the past. Suddenly, it stopped working.

Any idea how to make this work ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you installed the guest tools for VMWare into your VM?

Also check and make sure shared clipboard is enabled in the VM Settings